# Prolog Loops until True

Tags: prolog, primes

I'm pretty new to Prolog but I'm trying to get this program to give me the first set of twin primes that appears either at or above N.

```
twins(M) :- 
            M2 is M + 2,
            twin_prime(M, M2),
            write(M),
            write(' '),
            write(M2).
            M3 is M + 1,
            twins(M3).
```

However, I'm not completely sure how to go about getting it to loop and repeat until it's true. I've tried using the `repeat/0` predicate but I just get stuck in an infinite loop. Does anyone have any tips I could try? I'm pretty new to Prolog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track using tail recursion and @Jake Mitchell's solution works swell. But here are some tips that might help clarify a few basic concepts in Prolog:

First, it seems like your predicate `twins/1` is actually defining a relationship between *2* numbers, namely, the two twin primes. Since Prolog is great for writing very clear, declarative, relational programs, you might make the predicate more precise and explicit by making it `twin_primes/2`. (That this should be a binary predicate is also pretty clear from your name for the predicate, since one thing cannot be twins...)

One nice bonus of explicitly working with a binary predicate when describing binary relations is that we no longer have to fuss with IO operations to display our results. We'll simply be able to query `twin_primes(X,Y)` and have the results returned as Prolog reports back on viable values of `X` and `Y`.

Second, and more importantly, your current definition of `twins/1` wants to describe a *disjunction*: "`twins(M)` is true if M and M + 2 are both prime **or** if M3 is M + 3 and `twins(M3)` is true".  The basic way of expressing disjunctions like this is by writing *multiple clauses*. A single clause of the form `<Head> :- <Body>` declares that the `Head` is true if all the statements composing the `Body` are true. Several clauses with the same head, like `<Head> :- <Body1>. <Head> :- <Body2>. ...`, declare that `Head` is true if `Body1` is true **or** if `Body2` is true. (Note that a series of clauses defining rules for a predicate are evaluated sequentially, from top to bottom. This is pretty important, since it introduces non-declarative elements into the foundations of our programs, and it can be exploited to achieve certain results.)

In fact, you are only a small step from declaring a second rule for `twins/1`. You just tried putting both clause-bodies under the same head instance.  Prolog requires the redundant measure of declaring two different rules in cases like this. Your code should be fine (assuming your definition of `twin_prime/2` works), if you just change it like so:

```
twins(M)    :-  
            M2 is M + 2,
            twin_prime(M, M2),
            write(M),
            write(' '),
            write(M2).
twins(M)  :-
            \+twin_prime(M, M2),     %% `\+` means "not"
            M3 is M + 1,
            twins(M3).
```

Note that if you take advantage of Prolog's back-tracking, you often don't actually need to effect loops through tail recursion. For example, here's an alternative approach, taking into account some of what I advised previously and using a quick (but not as in "efficient" or "fast") and dirty predicate for generating primes:

```
prime(2).
prime(P) :-
    between(2,inf,P),
    N is (P // 2 + 1),
    forall(between(2,N,Divisor), \+(0 is P mod Divisor)).

twin_primes(P1, P2) :-
    prime(P1),
    P2 is P1 + 2,
    prime(P2).
```

`twin_primes/2` gets a prime number from `prime/1`, then calculates `P2` and checks if it is prime. Since `prime/1` will generate an infinite number of primes on backtracking, `twin_primes/2` will just keep asking it for numbers until it finds a satisfactory solution. Note that, if called with two free variables, this `twin_primes/2` will generate twin primes:

```
?- twin_primes(P1, P2).
P1 = 3,
P2 = 5 ;
P1 = 5,
P2 = 7 ;
P1 = 11,
P2 = 13 ;
P1 = 17,
P2 = 19 ;
P1 = 29,
P2 = 31 ;
```

But it will also verify if two numbers are twin primes if queried with specific values, or give you the twin of a prime, if it exists, if you give a value for `P1` but leave `P2` free:

```
?- twin_primes(3,Y). Y = 5.
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you this worked. What I kept trying to figure out and research that didn't go over well was what if it wasn't true. But no, that makes sense I need to create a second head/rule thing. This worked perfect. Thank you.

Comment: @tjg92 My pleasure and I'm glad I could help. It would be well worth your while to grok @Jake Mitchell's answer using the conditional operator too. I stressed the use of multiple clauses for 2 reasons: (1) it's the fundamental method of describing disjunctive sets of rules; (2) the use of `(condition -> <if true> ; <if false>)` can lull one into an imperative mind-set, which is counterproductive for students of Prolog. However, in this case, @Jake Mitchell's answer only requires `twin_prime/2` to be tried once, whereas my answer must retry it in the second clause to assure it turns out false.

Answer (score 1):

There's a handy if-then-else operator that works well for this.

```
twin_prime(3,5).
twin_prime(5,7).
twin_prime(11,13).

next_twin(N) :-
    A is N+1,
    B is N+2,
    (twin_prime(N,B) ->
     write(N),
     write(' '),
     write(B)
    ;
     next_twin(A)).
```

And a quick test:

```
?- next_twin(5).
5 7
true.

?- next_twin(6).
11 13
true.
```